# Why gdb casting is not working?

Tags: gdb

I use `print (CEthPacket*) 0xeb609a0` to examine an object at the given address and get `A syntax error in expression, near ') 0xeb609a0'.`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
CEthPacket is a C++ class and I'm on gdb Fedora (6.8-37.el5).

Answer (score 83):

I just ran in to similar issue, and, from a colleague of mine, I learnt that you need to provide the namespace that the class belongs to within a single quotes as following:

```
(gdb) p ('MyScope::MyClass'*) ptr;
```

Comment: And what about templates? How do I tell gdb that this value is a `std::vector<int>*`, for example?

Comment: @ulidtko The best I found is to use the mangled name. I made [a separate Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56467595/1896169), where I say barely more than that.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't say on which platform, which version of GDB, or what `CEthPacket` is.

My first guess is that you should try `print (struct CEthPacket *) 0xeb609a0` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Also your starting namespace is the one from current stack. If you want to start from root you have to use ::NS1::NS2::Obj.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into a very similar error.  It was caused because I was trying to reference an object that is not defined in the scope of the current stack frame.  Try changing to a stack frame where the CEthrPacket object is defined.