# How do I cast to a templated type?

Tags: gdb

In gdb, if you have a pointer to something, you can cast it before printing it.

For example, this works:

```
print *(int*) 0xDEADBEEF
```

However, how do I print a `std::vector<T>`? Specifically a `std::vector<std::string>`?

If it's `std::string`, I can do it with `std::__cxx11::string`, which `whatis std::string` outputs, but I can't convince gdb to like `std::vector<int>` (as an example). Quoting it doesn't help, as it says, `No symbol "std::vector<int>" in current context.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is by using the mangled name of the type. For example, the mangled name of `std::vector<int>` on current gcc and libstdc++ is `_ZSt6vectorIiSaIiEE`, which I found by compiling the following code on the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/t1pIil):

```cpp
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<int>) {}
// Mangled symbol name: _Z3fooSt6vectorIiSaIiEE
// _Z means "this is C++".
// 3foo means "identifier 3 chars long, which is `foo`"
// Strip those off and you're left with: St6vectorIiSaIiEE
// Add the _Z back: _ZSt6vectorIiSaIiEE
```

The mangled name of `std::vector<std::string>` is: `_ZSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE`, which can be verified with `whatis`.

Actually performing the cast:

```
print *(_Z3fooSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE*) 0xDEADBEEF
```