# GDB: How to cast memory address to STL object

Tags: c++, gdb

I am analyzing a core dump by using GDB. I know about a memory address that it is pointing to "std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >".

How to cast raw memory address to this template object on GDB prompt?

I tried by below command:

(gdb) p *('std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >' *)0x7fae3800b280
**No symbol "std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >" in current context.**

(gdb) p *(std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> > *)0x7fae3800b280
**A syntax error in expression, near `)0x7fae3800b280'.**

Comment: gdb is not, unfortunately, a C++ compiler, and only a complete C++ compiler can fully understand everything about the C++ type system, including templates and overloads. gdb can handle simple things, like pointers, and deal with it. But when it comes to non-trivial C++ constructs, like templates, gdb, sadly, doesn't have the requisite brain power. The short answer here: gdb can't do this, right now.

Comment: `std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >` is not a template, though to get that type from the template `std::basic_fstream` isnt the most trivial thing to do

Comment: @idclev463035818: I did not get you. Could you please elaborate more Or best would be to share exact command for my query

Comment: i was only adding to what Sam already said and tried to point you to a misunderstanding: `std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >` is not a template.

Comment: @idclev463035818: I am sorry, i still could not get you. 
basic_fstream is template only
template < class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
class basic_fstream;

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Thanks!
However i saw similar question where someone replied by using mangled name it is possible. I tried however did not work for me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467595/how-do-i-cast-to-a-templated-type)

Comment: sorry for the confusion. All I am trying to say is that `std::basic_fstream` is the template, while `std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >` is a concrete type (at runtime or during debugging there are no templates anymore)

Comment: Well, maybe you didn't mangle it correctly. But even if you did, I wouldn't expect this kind of a hacky workaround to be very reliable, or very practical to use every time. It is what it is, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried by below command:

Wild guess: do you have `set auto-solib-add off` in your `~/.gdbinit`?

The following example works fine for me:

```
cat t.cc
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::wfstream s("/dev/tty", s.out);
  for (int j = 0; j < argc; j++)
    s << j << " " << argv[j] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

g++ -g t.cc && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1235: file t.cc, line 8.
(gdb) run foo
Starting program: /tmp/a.out foo
0 /tmp/a.out
1 foo

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdc28) at t.cc:8
8         return 0;
(gdb) set print static off

(gdb) p s
$1 = {<std::basic_iostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >> = {<std::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >> = {<std::basic_ios<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >> = ...

(gdb) p &s
$2 = (std::wfstream *) 0x7fffffffd900

(gdb) p *('std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >' *)0x7fffffffd900
$3 = {<std::basic_iostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >> = {<std::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >> = {<std::basic_ios<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >> = {<std::ios_base> = ...
```

You should try to replicate above output.

If you can reproduce it, your tools are working as expected, and you need to concentrate on how you are analyzing the `core` dump.

If above example doesn't work as expected, you have *some* part of the toolchain which is misbehaving or misconfigured.

One way I was able to achieve `No symbol` result is by setting `auto-solib-add off`:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...

(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1235: file t.cc, line 8.
(gdb) set auto-solib-add off
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
0 /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc28) at t.cc:8
8         return 0;

(gdb) p &s
$1 = (std::wfstream *) 0x7fffffffd900

(gdb) p *('std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >' *) 0x7fffffffd900
No symbol "std::basic_fstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >" in current context.
```